# Dynamically load different css files in angular2 application based on user's language

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have an Angular2 application and it need to support multiple languages. Some of these languages may be RTL (i.e Persian) and some will be LTR (i.e. English). Apart from localizing strings, I need to style my components based on the direction of the language.

Now [using this helper](https://github.com/anasnakawa/bi-app-sass), I can have two separate files (i.e. app-rtl.scss & app-ltr.scss) which both import a single scss file (i.e. app.scss) which allows me to write my scss code in one place and automatically output two files; one for each direction.

The problem is now I need to somehow reference the suitable css file based on  the user's language. So if the user's language is English then I should have
`<link href="app-ltr.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the header and if it's RTL, `<link href="app-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Furthermore I want to add bootstrap to my project and that also has two different output files for LTR and RTL.

Is there any clean way to achieve this functionality?

#### What I've tried:

I've create two dummy component (one for LTR and one for RTL) without any template and then assign the respective scss file with `styleUrls` and  set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` so that it becomes a global style. Then I initialize both of them in my root component template with an *ngIf and check if the language is LTR or not.

This would work on the first page load because only one component (let's say component LTR) is active, but as soon as you change the language (i.e the second component (RTL) becomes active and thus LTR is removed) then the styles associated with the LTR stays on the page and is not removed. So then you have both RTL and LTR styles on your page which is not intended.

Comment: This can definitely be done with a loader like SystemJS, but if you are relying on Angular's Ahead of Time compilation, I suspect you will have trouble.

Comment: IMHO styles should be loaded per component and removed when component is destroyed. Please check my updated comment.

Answer (score 12):

You'd need to conditionally add or remove the style from the browser:

to add

```
loadIfNot(url,cssId){

     if (!document.getElementById(cssId)){
        var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link  = document.createElement('link');
        link.id   = cssId;
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = url;
        link.media = 'all';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }else{
        document.getElementById(cssId).disabled = false;///i fit's already there, enable it
    }

  }
```

and for remove

```
 disable(cssId){
     document.getElementById(cssId).disabled = true
 }
```

`Disable` and `Enable` is because browser tends to cache your styles, and in order to make them enable or disable, you'd change that attribute

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thank you so much (y)

Answer (score 5):

based on @marbug 's answer I would try to use a service and dynamically load and unload your "language" components.

that will work as follows

```
import { Injectable, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageAComponent } from "./language-a.component";
import { LanguageBComponent } from "./language-b.component";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class LanguageComponentService {
    componentRef: any;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private router: Router
    ) { }

    loadLanguageA(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LanguageAComponent);
        this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    }

   loadLanguageB(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(LanguageBComponent);
        this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    }


    unloadComponent() {
        this.componentRef.destroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more and how will i use this with css files

Comment: the post was talking about using dummy components with different style sheets and he can load and unload those components so as the styles to change

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could conditionally add a class to `<body>` based on the direction of the user's language? For example, `<body ng-class="{'dir-ltr': ltr, 'dir-rtl': !ltr}">`. Then of course you would have to wrap all your sass styles in `.dir-ltr` and `.dir-rtl`, respectively, so that the rest of the DOM would use the correct set of styles. This assumes that the language direction is resolved when the state loads, and also that `<body>` is within the scope of your angular app.

Answer (score 2):

1) I would suggest you to use lazy loaded modules instead of dynamic css files (please take a look at [official Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#lazy-load) for more info)

2) I would also suggest to put current language to some service, inject service into the appropriate component and to use needed css class. Advantages:

2.1) component style does not depend on body element - just on value in service - this is more good/correct for unit testing

2.2) there could be usecases when it's not enough to use LTR vs RTL classes, but to use some additional classes for particular languages (for instance, table columns could have different width for English, German, etc languages)

3) loading css dynamically could cause UI issues: initial styles are applied first and then they 'jump' to "other" styles (when the appropriate css file is loaded). So 1) & 2) are much better (IMHO indeed)

**UPDATE 2017-06-07** (just for being more clear)

*app-routing.module* could be like:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { 
        path: 'home', 
        loadChildren: 'app/my-home-page/my-home-page.module#MyHomePageModule' 
    },
    ...
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

*my-global.service* could be like:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGlobalService {
    currentLanguageDirection: string; // i.e. 'ltr' or 'rtl'
    currentLanguage: string;          // i.e. 'en', 'de', 'ru', etc
}
```

*my-home-page.component.ts* could be:

```
export class MyHomePageComponent {
    ...

    constructor(
        private myGlobalService: MyGlobalService, // inject global service
        ...
    ) {
    }

    ...
}
```

*my-home-page.component.html* could be:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="myGlobalService.currentLanguageDirection">
    <my-home-page-rtl *ngSwitchCase="'rtl'"></my-home-page-rtl>
    <my-home-page-ltr *ngSwitchDefault></my-home-page-ltr>
</div>
```

I.e. two additional components could be used: *my-home-page-ltr* and *my-home-page-rtl*. They will have separate scss|css files.

If you need unique implementation for German then *my-home-page-ltr.component.html* could be:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="myGlobalService.currentLanguage">
    <my-home-page-ltr-de *ngSwitchCase="'de'"></my-home-page-ltr-de>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
        ... (default html code)
    </div>
</div>
```

I.e. a separate *my-home-page-ltr-de* component will have separate scss|css for German.

P.S. Please note that you could reuse html files by setting them in @Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-home-page...',
    templateUrl: './my-home-page....html', // <-------------- reuse here
    styleUrls: ['./my-home-page....scss']
})
```

P.P.S. I would recommend **not** to use manually creation/deletion of components. Usage of *ngSwitch* or *ngIf* is a more correct way (IMHO)

P.P.P.S. Advantages are the following. Component and its children should be loaded/released by angular automatically. Language switching will be performed very fast because current component is loaded with its children - you do not need to load styles of all components during language switching.