# Reusable Sidenav in Angular2 Material Design

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have begun learning Angular2 and Material design. I want to create an app that has the below components. See below image for reference

1. Hamburger menu button. Tapping on it will reveal the side panel
2. Side panel. It will have several other options. This menu is common across all app screens

[image]

I have created 3 components as visible in the image. right-menu-component.html looks as below

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</md-sidenav>
```

I want to know how do I reveal this menu on tapping on the button, be it from the home screen or the about screen

The example in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav) show the implementation in a single page, but not as a reusable menu component

**Edit 1:** 
I would not like to place the button on the root page as some screens such as login, registration etc will not have the menu. But if placing them on the root page is a better approach and the button can be shown/hidden, I'll add it then.

**Edit 2:**
I tried using the example in the Angular docs without changing any line of code.

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">
    Jolly good!
  </md-sidenav>

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <button md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

When I click "open sidenav" button, it gives the below error in console

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./HomeComponent class HomeComponent - inline template:34:4 caused by: self._el_42.open is not a function
```

**Edit 3:**
Below are the versions of the modules

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.9.5
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.3
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

Comment: the obvious solution would be to put the button and sidebar on the root page and use <router-outlet></router-outlet> to change everything else

Comment: @elasticrash: Please read the edit. Also, can you share some code that invokes/reveals the right menu (sidenav) from different pages

Comment: there are other more slightly complex ways of achieving this like injecting a component dynamically into a view ...through a route guard for example. which is quite similar to this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602522/dynamically-load-different-css-files-in-angular2-application-based-on-users-lan/44111038#44111038

Answer (score 1):

Create a service which handles the connection between the sidenav and the toolbar.

**sidenav.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SidenavService {
  toggle = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**toolbar.component.ts**

```
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public sidenavService: SidenavService) { }
}
```

**toolbar.component.html**

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" fxLayout="row" color="none">
  <button ... (click)="sidenavService.toggle.emit()"> ... </button>
</md-toolbar>
```

**sidenav.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MdSidenav;

constructor(private sidenavService: SidenavService) {

    this.sidenavService.toggle
       .asObservable()
       .subscribe(
          () => this.sidenav.toggle()
       );
}
```

**sidenav.component.html**

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav>...</md-sidenav>
```

Comment: I tried the way you have described. Clicking the button gives the error "sidenav.toggle is not a function" in sidenav.component.ts. console.log(sidenav) prints "ElementRef {nativeElement: md-sidenav.app-sidenav}"

Comment: I've tested it once again, but for me it's working. Can you tell me more about your problem? Or which version of Material you are using

Comment: I've added the versions in Edit 3

Comment: If you are sure, you have done everything like me, try to update your packages. I'm working on angular 4.1.3, cli 1.1.0 and angular material beta-6, perhaps something has changed :-)

Comment: Updated material to 2.0 but getting lots of errors while compiling code. Also the example in the docs (https://material.angular.io/components/component/sidenav) seem to not work correctly in the Material website itself.