# Switch between two sass files in angular

Tags: angular, multilingual

I have for example the below sass files:

**style.scss**

```
body{
  direction:$direction;
  text-align:$start-direction;
}
```

**ltr.scss**

```
$direction: ltr;
$start-direction: left;
@import './style.scss';
```

**rtl.scss**

```
$direction: rtl;
$start-direction: right;
@import './style.scss';
```

and a service which changes the language of my website like:
**service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LangToggler {
  lang:any='en';

  toggle(lang) {
   //Here I want to change my css file  **switch between `RTL` and `LTR`**
  }
}
```

How can I dynamically switch between `RTL` and `LTR` files?
Have anyone any Idea, or a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ngClass. You can put the condition on ngClass and use different classes for different conditions. If you want further details, following might help:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: I agree - whack it on your `AppComponent` equivalent and let it cascade from there.

Comment: ngClass is not a good way to make the website multilingual, the website is not just a line to use ngClass, there are more than 200 pages. ngClass cannot help. I search a way to change the path of css dynamically in angular.json file for example

Comment: okay, i think the following discussion might help then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602522/dynamically-load-different-css-files-in-angular2-application-based-on-users-lan

Answer (score 0):

i had simillar problem but with regular css files. I was in situation where i needed to dynamicaly change whole css theme, for the whole project based on users company colors. The solution was to have helper class that would check if user is from company 1 then pull company1.css , if it's from company2 then company2.css. Something like this:

colorThemeHelper.ts

```
 const FACEBOOK = 'facebook';
 const TWITTER  = 'twitter';

 export class ThemeLoader {
     static setCss(): void {
        let url = '';
        let user: User = LocalData.getUser();

        switch (user.company) {
            case FACEBOOK:
                url = 'assets/css/facebook.css';
                break;
            case TWITTER:
                url = 'assets/css/twitter.css';
                break;
            default:
                url = '';
        }
        (<HTMLLinkElement>document.getElementById('ELEMENT_PLACEHOLDER_CSS')).href=url;
      }
  }
```

It's important that in index.html file you have link tag with some id ("ELEMENT_PLACEHOLDER_CSS" in my case) that you can get and put generated url from above method to that element's href attribute.

Than after the user has been logged in, in some dashboard component in ngOnInit method I would call setCss function! I know this is not the most elegant solution, and that you need to have separated css (or in your case sass) files, but it works in my case. Hope this helps!