# How to change the import of bootstrap css file dynamically in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

I have a multi-language website EN and AR.
Now I get bootstrap css from a CDN and change the cdn link based on the selected language.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Seeker</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/images/icon.svg" />
    <link
      id="bootstrap_css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

lang.service.ts

```
  setDir(lang = this.currentLang$.value) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      const linkTag = document.getElementById('bootstrap_css');
      if (lang === 'en') {
        document.dir = 'ltr';
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'en');
        linkTag?.setAttribute(
          'href',
          'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        );
      } else {
        document.dir = 'rtl';
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'ar');
        linkTag?.setAttribute(
          'href',
          'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css'
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

I don't want to use it from a cdn, I want to include the file from node_modules in angular.json but dynamically based on the selected language How can I do that?

angular.json

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", // if the selected lang is English
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css",  // if the selected lang is Arabic
  "src/styles/styles.scss"
],
```

If we can't update angular.json dynamically, then Can we import the file dynamically in style.scss?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602522/dynamically-load-different-css-files-in-angular2-application-based-on-users-lan ?

Comment: @Yogi In this way also I will use the cdn link of bootstrap, I need another method to use bootstrap from node_modules

Comment: @TonyNgo yes, I checked it, but there is no answer for my question

Answer (score 0):

Update your styles.scss file to dynamically import the styles based on the selected language:

```
$selectedLang: 'en'; // Set the selected language here

@if $selectedLang == 'en' {
  @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
} @else {
  @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css';
}

// Your other styles
@import 'src/styles/styles.scss';
```

Change the value of $selectedLang based on the selected language dynamically. You can achieve this by updating the variable in your Angular component or by using Angular services to dynamically set the language.

Comment: How to change the scss varibale at runtime?

Comment: You can achieve dynamic styling is by using Angular's Renderer2 service to manipulate the styles of an element.